# php form won't save in db

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I'm trying to make a collection of my movies. Part of my form (one about movie name, genre etc.) won't be saved in the database, even if another part with photo of movie will.

Here is the part that works:

```
<?php $mysqli = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'kolekcija');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {echo 'Doslo je do pogreske:';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();} if (!empty($_POST['btn_submit']))
    {

        $uploaddir = '/upload';
            $uploadfile = basename($_FILES['slika']['name']);
            $file_array = explode(".",$uploadfile);
            $ext = end($file_array);
            $size = filesize($_FILES['slika']['tmp_name']);
            $new_file_name = $uploaddir.$uploadfile;
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['slika']['tmp_name'], $new_file_name))
                    { $query = "INSERT INTO slike (file_path, file_name, file_ext, file_size) ";
                    $query .= "VALUES ('$uploaddir', '$uploadfile', '$ext', '$size')";
                        }
                        $rezultat = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
```

Here is the part that doesn't work:

```
$naslov = $_POST['nas'];
$zanr = $_POST['ID'];
$godina = $_POST['godina'];
$trajanje = $_POST['tra']; 
$upit = "INSERT INTO film (naslov, id_zanr, godina, trajanje)";
$upit .= "VALUES ('".$naslov."', '".$zanr."', '".$godina."', '".$trajanje."')";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $upit);}
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="unos.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> Naslov filma:<br /> 
<input type="text" name="nas" value="" /><br />
Zanr:<br /> <?php echo '<select name="ID">'; echo '<option value="0">Odaberite:</option>';
    $query_zanr = "SELECT * ";
    $query_zanr.= "FROM zanr ";
    $query_zanr.= "ORDER BY naziv ASC ";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_zanr);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { echo '<option value="'.$row["ID"].'">';
            echo $row["naziv"]; echo '</option>'; } echo '</select> <br/>';
?> Godina:<br /> 
<select name="godina">
  <option value=""> - Odaberite godinu - </option> 
  <?php for($i=1900; $i<2016; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="godina"> <?php echo $i; ?></option>
  <?php } ?> 
</select>
```

I'm not sure why I can't put rest of form with this, but it gives me an error, so here is rest of the form:

```
Trajanje:<br />
<input type="text" name="tra" value="" /><br />
Naslovna slika:<br />
<input type="file" name="slika" size="10"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Spremi" />
</form>
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: You're also missing a `/` for `$uploaddir = '/upload';` - PHP is translating that as `/uploadFILE.JPG`. You have no seperator in `$uploaddir.$uploadfile`.

Comment: Beware of SQL injection: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection

Comment: What is the error output?

Comment: it doesn't give error number or anything it just doesn't save in table "film" anything...but when i try to save over form it save photo and ai in table "film" continue to next number...for example i tried 3 times and i have 3 photos saved but table "film" is empty and next number in ai for film_id is 4 and not 1 even table is empty